# Custom hibernation command on Xubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, xubuntu, suspend, hibernate

I have found, that I have problems with hibernation on my machine running Xubuntu 15.10. With many attempts I found, that the only way to hibernate is to type following commands ([according to this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate)):

```
sudo -s
echo platform > /sys/power/disk
echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

My question is how to integrate this commands with "Hibernate" button in menu.